# Remove Gaussian Noise using filter2

Tags: image-processing, matlab, gaussian

How to use arithmetic mean filter to remove Gaussian noise of a gray level image by using `filter2` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First define a low-pass mask, for example

```
N = 5;
mask = ones(N)/N^2;
```

and then filter your image, say `X`, using

```
Y = filter2(mask,X);
```

Note that the mask has to be normalized, so that the filtered image has the same range of values as the original. Also, an all-ones mask is a very simple example; in practice there are better choices.

Comment: It does'nt remove the guassian noise but It gives me the white picture only.